# Why does the behavior like unset() in case of global variables is not the same for other operations too?

Tags: php, function, scope, global-variables, superglobals

As per the PHP documentation on unset() function :

**The behavior of unset() inside of a function can vary depending on what type of variable you are attempting to destroy.
If a globalized variable is unset() inside of a function, only the local variable is destroyed. The variable in the calling environment will retain the same value as before unset() was called.**

The code example demonstrating above saying is as below :

```
<?php
function destroy_foo() 
{
    global $foo;
    unset($foo);
}

$foo = 'bar';
destroy_foo();
echo $foo; // o/p is bar
?>
```

Now my question is why the above behavior is not applicable in following program that I have written?

```
<?php
function increment_foo() 
{
    global $foo;
    $foo++;
}

$foo = 36;
increment_foo();
echo $foo; // o/p is 37
?>
```

My doubt is why the behavior is different in above code than the behavior in the code written for `unset()` function?

In other words, I want to know in first code the `unset()` functionality remains limited to the local variable inside the function, it doesn't change the value in global scope outside the function but in the code that I have been written the increment functionality changes the value in global variable scope as well. In my code why it's not remaining limited to the local variable inside a function and changing value/affecting the variable outside the function as well?

Thank You.

Comment: seems to be a scope issue

Comment: That is how it works and how it is documented. Apart from that, it seems pretty logical to me: It is like a reference to the global variable so unsetting it, unsets the reference and modifying it changes the global variable. The real question is why you would use a global variable ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that using the `global` keyword will create a local variable referencing the variable in the global scope. Unsetting simply destroys this reference. It's similar to this piece of code:

```
$foo = 42;      // create variable with value
$bar = &$foo;   // create reference to $foo
$bar++;         // increment $foo via reference
unset($bar);    // destroy reference

var_dump($bar); // NULL
var_dump($foo); // 43
```

Another way to put it is that doing `global $foo` is just a shorthand for doing `$foo = &$GLOBALS['foo']`, e.g. the first example can be rewritten to

```
function increment_foo() 
{
    $foo = &$GLOBALS['foo'];
    $foo++;
    unset($foo);
    var_dump($foo); // NULL
}

$foo = 42;
increment_foo();
var_dump($foo); // 43
```

Maybe that makes it more obvious that you are only destroying the reference, e.g. you are destroying what points to `$foo`, but not `$foo` itself.